# Async task with concurrent and serially

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm not sure if the title is appropriate but I'll do my best to explain what I mean.

So I have code like this:

```
func syncData(forUser user: User, endPoints: [EndPoint]) {
    serialQueue.async{
        for endPoint in endPoints {
            // download the data in the internet using the provided endPoint (API). This may take longer to finish depends on the connection speed and data begin downlod
        }
    }
}
```

This method performs number of tasks "serially". The tasks for each user should be done "serially" because they are depended to each other and this method works ok it able to download the data from the internet.

The problem is when the downloading of data takes time. Let's say user1 performs data download and the process takes time to finish, while the tasks of user1 is being process user2 performs data download also. Since user1 isn't done yet user2 will have to wait 'til everything is done for user1. Because of this my progress bar for user2 remain to 0 until all of user1 is done.

Is there a way to group all tasks of user1 and user2 (separately) and still be done serially. And each group should be performed concurrently, 
 so each group won't wait for the other group to finish before it performs its tasks.

Comment: By the way, you say "This method performs number of tasks 'serially'". Not necessarily so. It depends upon what you're doing inside that `for` loop. And if they're really doing downloads (and if you're doing that right), those generally will be asynchronous and therefore will be happening concurrently with respect to the downloads for even a given user `for` loop.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for that, I wasn't able to change that. The serialQueue is variable in the same class of that method.

Comment: What's funny is that your original example, before you edited the question, in which you created a separate background queue for each call, would have accomplished what you were asking for, allowing these to run concurrently. Or if this queue really is just for handling this one `async` call in this method, you could just make the queue a concurrent queue (my prior comment about the serial nature of your `for` loop notwithstanding) and that would also let separate `async` calls run concurrently with respect to each other.

Comment: @Rob, on the `for` loop the data is being downloaded using the "endPoint" and we made it in a way that it will block the `for` loop until the download is done then move to the next "endPoint". I believe it works ok as we're able to see the data in the Realm database.

Comment: OK, if that's what you're doing in that `for` loop (and I'll refrain from editorializing on that pattern), then your simple `async` to either to a unique queue each time or to a concurrent queue will accomplish what you want, where one call to your `syncData` will not wait for the prior call to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate queue for each user according to their unique id's. Then in this function, run your code on the queue assigned to that particular user.

**OR**

You can maintain an array of all the queues. When a user requests an action, see if they already have a queue assigned to them in the array. If yes, then put the task in that queue. If not, then create a new queue, assign it to that user and put the task on it.